# Get Merchant Details in PayPal SDK

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using PayPal .NET SDK https://github.com/paypal/permissions-sdk-dotnet to process third party merchant payments.

I am able to get the merchant token, create express checkout payments and claim them. For the whole process to work, I need merchant billing email id, paypal accountid and paypal name. I plan to use GetBasicPersonalDataReq for the same.

The bad thing is that I am  not sure where to pass merchant credentials to obtain its merchant information.

```
        var attributes = new PersonalAttributeList();
        attributes.attribute.Add(PersonalAttribute.HTTPAXSCHEMAORGCOMPANYNAME);
        attributes.attribute.Add(PersonalAttribute.HTTPSWWWPAYPALCOMWEBAPPSAUTHSCHEMAPAYERID2);

        var request = new GetBasicPersonalDataRequest(attributes);

        var service = new PermissionsService();
        var response = service.GetBasicPersonalData(request);
```

Thanks, 
Naveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally got an answer. The PayPal allows you to set token and token secret when requesting for third party information.

A sample code for above problem

```
            var attributeList = new PersonalAttributeList();
            attributeList.attribute.Add(PersonalAttribute.HTTPAXSCHEMAORGCOMPANYNAME);
            attributeList.attribute.Add(PersonalAttribute.HTTPAXSCHEMAORGCONTACTEMAIL);
            attributeList.attribute.Add(PersonalAttribute.HTTPSWWWPAYPALCOMWEBAPPSAUTHSCHEMAPAYERID2);

            var personalDataReq = new GetBasicPersonalDataRequest(attributeList);

            var service = new PermissionsService();
            service.setAccessToken("token from paypal");
            service.setAccessTokenSecret("token secret from paypal");

            var personalDataInfo = service.GetBasicPersonalData(personalDataReq);
```

The third party token and token secret are obtained from PayPal when you are requesting permissions from PayPal for third party access

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to defining the merchant you're trying to look up with the GetBasicPersonalData request?

It is, unfortunately, more complicated than just passing a piece of the subjects account information. The entire process is summarized by this flow: 
RequestPermissions -> GetAccessToken -> generate oAuth signature -> GetBasicPersonalData

The bottom of this guide goes through the full explanation of getting basic or advanced data:
https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_PermissionsUsing

Comment: Yeah, I had read that but PayPal documentation is a pain. No where they have mentioned about how to work with third party tokens clearly. 

Thanks for the link, I have already seen that. Updated my answer to help others stuck in similar situation.

Comment: It can be kind of a drag to go through. Especially for calls like this that are kind of new and not widely used. 
If you have some recommendations on changes to make I can submit doc updates.

Comment: I would definitely have that kind of documentation and code sample update. Considering we do not have any sort of sdk documentation available except the sample code, I had to read through API signature to understand where to pass correct parameters.